# How can I get websockify working on Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket

I'm working on a web app that needs to connect to an existing server that only allows TCP connections, not WebSocket connections. Since modern browsers do not allow TCP sockets, the solution I've come up with is to set up a middleware somewhere, in the form of websockify (https://github.com/kanaka/websockify). I run it once with a given websocket port and it will route the messages it receives from this port to the server, and from the server back to my app. This setup allows for many instances of my app to be run at once and routed through the single running instance of the middleware, which is nice. This works well locally, but I'm having trouble setting it up on Heroku.

My `Procfile` looks like this (server host and port omitted):

```
web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT
startserver: bundle exec ruby websockify.rb $PORT [server_host]:[server_port]
```

After I push my changes to Heroku I type in the command line `heroku run startserver`, and it responds (for instance):

```
Starting server on :13689
  0: {"listen_host"=>nil, "listen_port"=>13689, "target_host"=>[server_host], "target_port"=>[server_port]}
```

, which seems to indicate it's working. For a while I assumed the two $PORTs would be the same value, but the websocket binds to a different port than the web applications do, although I think this is intentional behaviour. Still, I can't seem to connect to the WebSocket, even through the javascript console. I wrote a function for the console:

```
function test_port(schema, port) {ws = new WebSocket(schema + "://" + window.document.location.host + port, ["binary"]); ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; ws.onmessage = function(msg) {console.log(msg);}; ws.onclose = function() {console.log("Closed");};};
```

I've run this function on a few different inputs to try to figure out what's getting lost (besides me).

```
> test_port("ws", ":13689");  // the port it should be listening on
Closed
> test_port("ws", ":42069");  // web app's port
Closed
> test_port("ws", ":5555");  // nonsense number
Closed
> test_port("ws", "");   // use default
Unexpected response code: 200 
Closed
> test_port("ws", ":80");   // default
Unexpected response code: 200 
Closed
> test_port("wss", ":13689");
Closed
> test_port("wss", ":42069");
Closed
> test_port("wss", ":5555");
Closed
> test_port("wss", "");   // use default
Unexpected response code: 200 
Closed
> test_port("wss", ":443");   // default
Unexpected response code: 200 
Closed
```

None of these seem to be working. The defaults give an HTTP OK response before also closing down immediately, but there seems to be a bug in Chrome that fails on a 200 rather than the intended 101. Setting the port directly to 443 on websockify's startup causes a binding error, since Heroku wants you to bind through their ports.

I think I can figure out the rest of the application if I can figure out how to connect to my middleware from the browser. Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? It feels like I'm close, but I'm not sure what else I can do. Let me know if you need more information about the project to help me troubleshoot it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that websockify was the wrong tool for the job. Websocket connections to heroku apps are routed to the default port (80 for ws, 443 for wss), but you do not access them by binding to a port. You receive them as an HTTP request (I think?), and have to check yourself if it's requesting a Websocket connection. I don't know if websockify would let me do this, but it certainly wasn't the way I was running it, so it was easier for my purposes to write my own small middleware in Ruby, routing the websocket messages to the TCP server and the TCP messages through the websocket connection. It was fairly straightforward once I figured out where the websocket would try to connect, and with the help of this site https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets .